# back button action bar missing - navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-layout

I started building my navigation drawer, the problem now is when I click on one of item from my list I  go to the DetailActivity but I don't see the back-arrow button that allows me to go back to parent activity. I tried setting  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) as suggested here: https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html but it didn't work. Please, can anyone show me how to fix this?

here's my code https://github.com/probelalkhan/android-navigation-drawer-example/tree/master/app/src/main/java/net/simplifiedcoding/navigationdrawerexample

Comment: Where do you want to show back button (In which screen)? You only have one activity and you're are replacing fragments on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how is setup a back button for my DetailActivity:

Inside Your MainActivity.java -> inside your onCreate() class add this:

```
// toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Then go to the manifests file, set the parent activity for the DetailActivity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    ></activity>
```

Hope it works for you

Comment: thanks I tried that and it didnt work